# node.js : install express module got error & return log file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, installation

How do I install the express module in Macintosh globally & locally?

I got the following error during installation & return `npm-debug.log` file:

> node.js : install express module got error & return log file

Comment: We need some more information.  Showing us your `npm-debug.log` will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are getting permissions issues try installing with sudo for the global install

Globally `sudo npm install -g express`

Locally would just be `npm install express`